# Where does this function have a derivative of zero? Where is it not differentiable?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, solution-verification

> Use the following graph to answer the questions.
>   [image]

**Did I answer these questions correctly?** I sketched the derivative roughly on the same grid, then noted (estimated) where the derivative was zero. I then noted where the graph 'jumped' when approaching a point from either side, or where the limit as x approached a point differed from the right and the left.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well in your answer to the first question you say that the function has a derivative of zero at $x=8$ and in your answer to the second question you say that it is not differentiable at $x=8$. That's a contradiction.

Comment: I'm guessing the derivative doesn't equal zero at x=8, because I am sure that it is not differentiable at that point. Am I right in thinking that?

Comment: That's correct. Your other answers should be right as well, it is just a little hard to see on this picture where exactly the function is not defined at $x\approx 4$.